# Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 13 Plus Fix Speakers/ Microphone and Webcam

Tags: sound, dell, microphone, webcam, xps

I already did a lot of research on the topic, this post (it's not from me) https://forum.manjaro.org/t/speakers-microphone-camera-not-detected-on-new-dell-xps-9320/114351/15 describes my situation very well. I can't get speakers/ microphone and webcam to work. I got the Dell XPS 13 Plus with Windows installed and installed plain Ubuntu and worked forward from there. Btw, the Wifi drivers I already had to built by myself. If I attach an headphone via the Thunderbolt port it works and I can hear something.

```
    $ inxi -SMA

System:
  Host: m-XPS-9320 Kernel: 5.13.0-52-generic x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 9320 v: N/A
  serial: <superuser/root required>
  Mobo: Dell model: 0V0059 v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required>
  UEFI: Dell v: 1.4.0 date: 05/13/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A
  Device-2: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-52-generic
```